# What is this: data-wplink-url-error="true" and why is it added to my links?

Tags: tinymce, links

WordPress sometimes adds this to links created by the visual inline link editor:

```
data-wplink-url-error="true"
```

Why? What does this do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're inserting a link in the tinymce editor, there is a [piece of javascript](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/plugin.js) that checks whether the link looks like a url. If it doesn't it inserts this string into the anchor tag. Later on in the code, this tag is tested for to enable issuing a warning to the user that the link is probably invalid.